# Convert text date and time to a real date time in excel

Tags: excel, date, time, data-conversion

My data is extracted from an application and it has a text that looks like a date/time in excel. How do I actually convert "2023-06-13, 10:47:25" (in text) to a real date/time conversion? I've tried Text to Columns but it doesn't work.

I've tried Text to Columns but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use formula:

```
=SUM(VALUE(TEXTSPLIT(A1,", ")))
```

And then format cell as you want:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula and format cell as `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`

```
=1*SUBSTITUTE(A1,", "," ")
```

[image]